# Network Request failed while sending image to server with react native

Tags: image, react-native, post, server, fetch

i want to send image to a server and getting the result with a json format but the application returns a Network Request failed error

> react native 0.6  using genymotion as emulator

i tried RNFetchblob but the result take a long time to get response (5 min ) 
also i tried axios but it response with empty data with 200 ok

this is the function that import the image

```
 OnClick = () => {
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {
      console.log("Response = ", response);

      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log("User cancelled image picker");
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log("Image Picker Error: ", response.error);
      } else {
        let source = { uri: response.uri };

        // You can also display the image using data:
        //let source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };

        this.setState({
          avatarSource: source,
          data: response.data,
          BtnDisabled: false
        });
        console.log();
      }
    });
  };
```

and this method that sends the image

```
 Send = async () => {


     let url = "http://web001.XXX.com:8000/api/prediction/check_prediction/";
     let UplodedFile = new FormData();
     UplodedFile.append('file',{  type:'image/jpeg', uri :  this.state.avatarSource , name:'file.jpeg'});
     fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body:UplodedFile

     })
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(response => {
       console.log("success");

        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
```

i expect json format

[ScreenShot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y64ST.png)

Comment: Ready my question here, it may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57112022/react-native-android-app-throws-network-error-when-upload-on-app-store/57113327#57113327

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you change your code like this?

```
OnClick = () => {
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {
      console.log("Response = ", response);

      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log("User cancelled image picker");
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log("Image Picker Error: ", response.error);
      } else {
        let source = { uri: response.uri };

        // You can also display the image using data:
        //let source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };

        this.setState({
          pickerResponse: response,
          data: response.data,
          BtnDisabled: false
        });
        console.log();
      }
    });
  };
```

```
Send = async () => {
     let url = "http://web001.XXX.com:8000/api/prediction/check_prediction/";
     let UplodedFile = new FormData();
     UplodedFile.append('file',{  type:'image/jpeg', uri : this.state.pickerResponse.path , name:'file.jpeg'});
     axios({
        method: "post",
        url: url,
        data: UplodedFile
      })
     .then(response => {
       console.log("success");

        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
```